How to change eval (due to CSP Implemenation)
is there are any easier way to remove eval() with different methods as I have a used alot in my code but it fails CSP.
sample code:
eval("documents.forms[0].byr"+x).disabled=false;

$('form:eq(0) [name="byr' + x + '"]').prop('disabled', false);


There's no general solution, every use has to be examined and changed on a case by case basis.

document.forms[0]["byr"+x].disabled=false;  converting to [tag:jquery] would require substantial changes : https://jsfiddle.net/ry70nphb/
